# Implementing FormulaJS client side only?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I could do with some help implementing FormulaJS - Client side only. I have an excel file with several formulas to be converted into javascript.

The FormulaJS documentation says to use requireJS but I'm unable to implement it correctly. I got the following error:

Uncaught Error: Module name "lib/compatibility" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

This is my document header:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Calc tests</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/requirejs-master/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/formula.js-master/index.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/what-income.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked a question which has its own answer:

> If the error message includes Use require([]), then it was a top-level
>   require call (not a require call inside a define() call) that should
>   be using the async, callback version of require to load the code:

```
require(['foo'], function (foo) {
    //foo is now loaded.
});
```

So what you probably have in your code has a `node.js` require style, instead of `callback version of require to load the code`.

I think it is what you have in **`js/formula.js-master/index.js`** path:

```
var categories = [
  require('./lib/compatibility'),
  require('./lib/database'),
  require('./lib/engineering'),
  require('./lib/logical'),
  require('./lib/math-trig'),
  require('./lib/text'),
  require('./lib/date-time'),
  require('./lib/financial'),
  require('./lib/information'),
  require('./lib/lookup-reference'),
  require('./lib/statistical'),
  require('./lib/miscellaneous')
];

for (var c in categories) {
  var category = categories[c];
  for (var f in category) {
    exports[f] = exports[f] || category[f];
  }
}
```

And if you take a better look at your code you will see:

```
var compatibility = require('./lib/compatibility');
```

which has the nodejs style of `require` and is not ***async***, whereas if you want to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) you should do it like:

```
require(['./lib/compatibility'], function (compatibility) {
    //your code goes here
});
```

The final conclusion is, you are using the wrong require library. What is the correct one?

Fortunately there is one, which can be really useful to use nodejs modules in browser: **[Browserify](http://browserify.org/)**

You can find demos **[here](http://browserify.org/demos.html)**, it is said like:

> Browsers don't have the **require** method defined, but **Node.js** does. With
>   **Browserify** you can write code that uses require in the same way that
>   you would use it in Node.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try Browserify and post back if successfull on not.

Comment: Thanks, yep it did work! After a day and 1/2 working on errors installing Browserify on Mac OsX.

Comment: Yep, it has always been a painful process to get started with node modules but it gets easier as you go further. I would definitely recommend you to give [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) a go for your scaffolding process which is really helpful.

Comment: @user3744945 check this [generator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-browserify) out, this accelerates using browserify and also helps you keep up with the latest practices as well.

Comment: @user3744945 I was wondering if it's been a helpful answer, are you going to accept it:)

Comment: Sorry :D, first time I have used it (posted a question!), a bit unfamiliar with the process! Definitely helpful!